# How to make n nested for loop in C or Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, loops

How to do something like this

```
for(int a = 0; a<2; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b<2; b++){
            for(int c = 0; c<2; c++){
                for(int d = 0; d<2; d++){

                    n[a+b+c+d]=x[a]*y[b]*z[c]...
}}}}
```

But i have x [n]...

Comment: Never mind the how... Why? (Or is this some form of "poor maintainability" contest or something?)

Comment: This is coding for job security.

Comment: Its still a bit dazzling what you're actually trying to achieve... but probably you have to solve this recursively (although I suspect you misinterpreted your requirements to come to needing this sort of thing).

Comment: Quite a good question (but poorly described). Looks to me that it can be reduced to 2 nested loops... somehow.

Comment: This *is* an interesting question, but only in the context of my personal curiosity/learning. I can't think of a situation where I'd do this in production code.

Comment: Well I am trying to get tensor product of n complex vector spaces and it should be * instead of + but it is the same.

Comment: So is it really intentional that n[1] is first assigned x[0]*y[0]*z[0]*r[1], then overwritten by x[0]*y[0]*z[1]*r[0], then overwritten by x[0]*y[1]*z[0]*r[0], then by x[1]*y[0]*z[0]*r[0]?

Answer (score 3):

Recursively:

```
void do_sum(double *n, double *x, int limit, int index, double sum)
{
    if (limit == 0)
        n[index] = sum;
    else
        for (int a = 0; a<2; a++)
            do_sum(n, x, limit-1, index+a, sum+x[a]);
}
```

To initiate the recursion, start with `do_sum(n, x, max_n, 0, 0)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i made i mistake in my question so if you could help me with the similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

@jbx is right: recursively is the way to go.  Assuming `n[]` and `x[]` are globals:

```
void
work(int depth, int n_index, int x_total)
{
    if (depth == 0) {
        n[n_index] = x_total;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            work(depth-1, n_index+i, x_total+x[i]);
        }
    }
}

void
do_multidimensional_thing(int depth)
{
    work(depth, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the depth for these is just 2 for each dimension., i.e., 2 * N total posibilities.
Something that is weird that is it will access the same element in n[] for different values, overwriting things:

a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, d = 1
a = 1 , b = 1, c = 0, d = 0
...

n[a + b + c + d] is actually just indexing into n[2] for C(4,2) etc.
I think the actual question should be flagged and re-thought.

This doesn't seem like a well-thought question.

But if anything - I would go with the backtracking (recursion) method, if that's really what the user wants. (especially if there's N dimensions - as there's no real great way of doing this thing iteratively, unless you want to apply dp on this, which is probably over the head of the end user)

Comment: It's interesting that both Ned and I read this as asking for a sum of these values (so n[...]+=x[]...). My guess is still that this is what is actually meant.

Comment: Quite possibly - but it's not what was asked :)